# Inter a php array in textarea and return the same array using $_POST

Tags: php

I have an array array('a'=>'one','b'=>'two')
I am entering the array as an input of textarea. After post I want to get the same array via `$_POST`.

```
<textarea name="myinput">array('a'=>'one','b'=>'two')</textarea>

$_POST['myinput'];
```

In the result I am getting string instead of array

Comment: you can't do it directly, because text-area value came as string

Comment: how to get the array as it is? can i covert the string to array

Comment: For what purpose you are using this ?

Comment: http://php.fnlist.com/php/serialize

Comment: I want to do this for my client, please enter array('a'=>'one','b'=>'two') it will give you a serialize data

Comment: how to achieve like  http://php.fnlist.com/php/serialize

Comment: [You will find answer here](http://us3.php.net/print_r)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
<form>
...
<input type="text" name="yourArray[a]" value="one">
<input type="text" name="yourArray[b]" value="two">
...
</form>
```

and then in your PHP script:

```
if (!empty($_POST['yourArray'])) {
// do something with $_POST['yourArray']
```

Comment: i want to input the array at once in text input like array('a'=>'one','b'=>'two')